# High-order complex derivative in MATLAB

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods, matlab

First derivative can be calculated by the complex-step derivative formula:

$f'(x)=\frac{Im(f(x+ih))}{h}$

Generalization of the above for calculating derivatives of any order employs multicomplex numbers, resulting in multicomplex derivatives:

$f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{C^{(n)}_{n^2-1}(f(x+i^{(1)}h+i^{(n)}h))}{h^n}$

According to the Wiki [Complex-variable methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Complex-variable%20methods):

[image]

In Matlab, the calculation of the first order derivative is very easy to implement:

```
x=0:0.01:10;
h=0.001;
f=sin(x);
df=imag(sin(x+h*i))./h;
plot(x,f)
hold on
plot(x,df)
```

I do not understand how to implement the calculation of the second order derivative, because I do not understand what is $i^{(1)},i^{(2)}...i^{(n)}$ and how the operator $C^{(n)}_{n^2-1}$ is calculated.

EDIT: Here is the program for the second order derivative, which is calculated incorrectly. I don't understand how to use $Imag_{12}$

```
x=0:0.01:15;
h=0.0000001;
imx1=x+(i)*h;
imx2=x+(i+i)*h;
f=(x).^2;
df = imag((imx1).^2)./h;
ddf = imag((imx2).^2)./h^2;
```

Comment: http://ancs.eng.buffalo.edu/pdf/ancs_papers/2008/complex_step08.pdf In this article, I found the formula ((8), page 4), but did not understand the relationship with the formula from Wikipedia.

Comment: The formula from this article for the 2nd derivative works.

Comment: Use truncated Taylor expansions. The propagation of those through elementary functions and operations is well-known. The complex-step derivative is just an approximation of dual numbers or linear Taylor expansions.

Comment: @LutzLehmann This approach works, but it fails when searching for the 3rd order derivative, because its calculation requires the difference between the approximate and exact value of the first order derivative.

Comment: There is a more immediate concern. Without adding theoretical knowledge about the functions, as in the Taylor series operations, the complex-step and any variations work with just the numerical functions. But these are designed to minimize the relative error, without regard to the derivatives. So while the first derivative might still be close due to functional and differential identities, higher-order derivatives will be increasingly wrong.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I don't need high precision. I want to understand how the scheme of this numerical method is built and so that the nature of the behavior of the derivatives is more or less correctly displayed. That's all I need for now.

Comment: The advantage of the simple complex-step method is that the math library already contains all the complex operations. An implementation of multicomplex numbers $\Bbb C^{\otimes_{\Bbb R} n}$ would require an extra library that implements the tensor operations on top of a Taylor series implementation. It would be just easier to short-cut that directly to the Taylor series part. Additionally, instead of manipulating objects of size $n^2$ the truncated Taylor expansions are only of size $n$.

Comment: https://www.autodiff.org/Docs/euroad/13rd%20EuroAd%20Workshop%20-%20Thierry%20Dargent%20-%20Using%20Multicomplex%20Variables%20for%20Automatic%20Computation%20of%20High-Order%20Derivatives.pdf (page 11) I more or less understood how the numerical scheme is built. I did not understand how to take the imaginary part of a number in the process of calculations using an operator of the form $Imag_{12}$. See edit please

Comment: That article is "sour grapes", a la "I do not understand Taylor propagation, thus it is incredibly hard". In the context of AD, Taylor propagation is as complicated as dual numbers, aka first derivatives forward differentiation. Mixed higher derivatives will always be complicated, there is a trade-off of huge memory footprints vs. numerical stability. The multi-complex case falls into the huge memory footprint direction, similar to the cross-derivatives approach I was once working at. There is a middle region of derivatives in 2 to 3 directions where both approaches work equally well.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you! I appreciate it. In one of the topics, I saw your comment about the use of either dual numbers or hypercomplex numbers (correct me if I'm wrong). And as I understand it, you are very seriously involved in this topic. I am interested in the development of various computational procedures for derivatives (Matlab, Mathematica), and additionally motivation is reinforced by an article from the wiki about the use of dual numbers to calculate derivatives. If you shared any links (including to your work), then I would be very happy and deal with this topic at my leisure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Since you're using Matlab, a simpler approach is to create a [Jordan block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix) matrix
$$\eqalign{
&J = (xI + N) \; \in\,\bbR{n\times n} \\
&N^n = 0 \qquad \big\{{\rm nilpotent}\big\}
}$$
Have Matlab evaluate the function using this matrix as its argument, and since
$$f(J) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{N^k\,f^{(k)}(x)}{k!}$$
the $k^{th}$ derivative can be read off of the $k^{th}$ superdiagonal of the result for $\,1\le k<n$